Spring Security resource server JWT with session creation
I have a front end app which obtains ID token from Google. This token is valid for 1 hour.
When user logs in I want to use this token to either create an account if it doesn't exist in my back end or get the user if it exists.
Since the token is only valid for 1 hour I cannot use it for securing the endpoints without expecting from user to login every hour (which is not acceptable). I figured I need to somehow create and maintain an http session in the back end and store the session key in the cookie.
My question is how do I do that with Spring Boot 3 and Spring Security 6?
EDIT:
After reading this documentation I thought that I can do the following:
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain jwtAuthentication(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.securityMatcher("/user/jwt/**");
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.anyRequest().authenticated());
        http.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth -> oauth.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));
        http.securityContext(sc -> sc.securityContextRepository(new DelegatingSecurityContextRepository(
                new RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository(),
                new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository()
        )));
        http.cors(c -> c.configurationSource(
                r -> {
                    CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
                    corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:3000"));
                    corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("*"));
                    corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
                    corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
                    return corsConfiguration;
                }
        ));
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain myAuthentication(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> {
            authorize.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").permitAll();
        });
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.anyRequest().authenticated());
        http.securityContext(sc -> sc.securityContextRepository(new DelegatingSecurityContextRepository(
                new RequestAttributeSecurityContextRepository(),
                new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository()
        )));
        http.cors(c -> c.configurationSource(
                r -> {
                    CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
                    corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:3000"));
                    corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("*"));
                    corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
                    corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
                    return corsConfiguration;
                }
        ));
        return http.build();
    }
}

The idea behind this is to use the first bean to authenticate requests with JWT and then "switch" to the second bean and use the session token for further authentication.
So, the front end would first send the following request with JWT in order to create an account:
  await useFetch("http://localhost:8080/user/jwt/me", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${response.credential}`
    },
    onResponse({request, response, error}) {      
      if (response.status === 200) {console.log("success");
      }
    }
  });

Response to this request contains:
Set-Cookie
    JSESSIONID=AFEE91E26315A9F82B73E306A88087D7; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None

and the cookie is saved in the browser.
Then subsequent requests should use this cookie in order to authenticate (that's the second SecurityFilterChain bean in the configuration). For example:
$fetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/endpoint`, {
    method: "POST",
    credentials: "include",
    body: {
      entityId: entityId,
      entityType: entityType,
    },
    onResponse({request, response, error}) {
      if (response.status === 201) {
        console.log("success");
      }
    }
  });

The "credentials: include" is key here in order to send the cookies.
After this request I get 403 error even though the cookie is sent.
There is 1 more thing I think I should mention: Since I'm using social login (Google), "g_state" cookie is sent alongside JSESSIONID cookie.

all of this is already built into spring security https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/core.html#oauth2login-sample-redirect-uri

@Toerktumlare could you please provide an example? I have read the docs, however I don't understand.

No, i dont have random code examples laying around, i suggest you instead read the documentation, and then use the edit button on your question and include and ask about what parts of the documentation you dont understand and i will explain.

@Toerktumlare I have read more documentation, and edited my question in hopes that the problem is clearer now. I'm also thinking about going for the complete custom authentication mechanism (maybe that's the answer here). Anyway, looking forward to your comment!

you have it all wrong, you send a JWT in your first request, but i dont understand why you think you are getting an authenticated cookie back. You are getting a session cookie, but that session cookie is not authenticated. Why do you think it is? oauth2ResourceServer is stateless it AUTHORIZES that specific request and then nothing more. It does not AUTHENTICATE

i recommend you use the pre implemented google client that is in the documentation that will automatically log you in with google and supply a session cookie to the browser. You dont need JWTs at all

@Toerktumlare I need to send JWT in the first request because I want to make an account out of the Google user. The JWT provides the data. I think the session cookie is enough for the further auth because the docs says so - "Subsequent requests include the session cookie which is used to authenticate the user for the remainder of the session." I didn't understand what library are you refering to? FE or BE? I don't need to call Google's API. I just need Google to provide me with identity of a user, and then switch to another form of authentication.

But you are getting the jwt from somewhere, i presume google. You should never have a JWT in the browser. Your user should initiate a login with your backend, your backend redirects the browser to to google. The user authenticates with google and google then redirects you back to your backend with a specific code. Your backend takes this code and exchanges it with google for a JWT. Your backend then uses this jwt to fetch user information and takes that info to create a user in your database. Backend then takes and generates a authenticated session that it sticks in a cookie.

This cookie is then handed put to the browser. As you can see if you read my explanation, the jwt never leaves the backend. All i just explained is already implemented in spring security and is called oauth2login and spring has a pre implemented module that talks to google. What you are building is homemade security dont do that. And im done writing here good luck.
